# Not able to install power pivot add in in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, installation, powerpivot

This message is showing when i double click on setup.

[image]

please help me to install it .I have read all the installation instruction . My pc is 64 bit and i have downloaded 64 bit power pivot.

Comment: So do you have Excel 2010 installed?

Comment: The message refers to Excel, and needing to match 32 vs. 64 bits with Excel.

Comment: You install the wrong bit version Add-in for Excel. You should re-install the correct bit version add-in.

Comment: I got it . You are right . Thank you